# merging multiple dataframes with the same columns and remove nans

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Suppose I have the following **main** df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'name':['Sara',  'John', 'Christine']})
```

df:

```
    name
0   Sara
1   John
2   Christine
```

Now I have 4 other dfs with age and grade for the 3 usernames but with different NaN arrangement:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'name':['Sara',  'John', 'Christine'],

               'age': [26, 30, np.nan]})
```

df3:

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'name':    ['Sara',  'John', 'Christine'],

                   'age': [np.nan, 30, 24]})
```

df4:

```
df4 = pd.DataFrame({'name':    ['Sara',  'John', 'Christine'],

                   'grade': [np.nan, 1, 3]})
```

df5:

```
df5 = pd.DataFrame({'name':    ['Sara',  'John', 'Christine'],

                   'grade': [12, np.nan, 3]})
```

I want to merge the data from the 4 dataframes to the main `df` on `name` column and remove NaNs.

What I did so far:

Created a list of dfs:

```
dfs = [df,df2,df3,df4,df5]
```

used `reduce`:

```
from functools import reduce

df_final = reduce(lambda left,right: pd.merge(left,right,on='name'), dfs)
```

df_final:

```
    name          age_x     age_y   grade_x     grade_y
0   Sara           26.0      NaN      NaN       12.0
1   John           30.0      30.0     1.0       NaN
2   Christine       NaN      24.0     3.0       3.0
```

**Expected output:**

df_final:

```
    name          age        grade
0   Sara          26.0        12        
1   John          30.0        1.0       
2   Christine     24.0        3.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try merging long with [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) then using [`groupby first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html) to retrieve the first valid entry for each column per name:

```
merged = (
    pd.concat(dfs).groupby('name', sort=False, as_index=False).first()
)
```

`merged`:

```
        name   age  grade
0       Sara  26.0   12.0
1       John  30.0    1.0
2  Christine  24.0    3.0
```